# setting opener property on iframe

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

The framework I'm using (Django admin) pops up a new window when adding new items to the database. I would like to use a light box instead of popping up a new window (fancybox for now), and I'm using the iframe option. However, when I click save in the iframe, a request gets sent to the server, and the server responds with a page contains only the JavaScript code: `opener.dismissAddAnotherPopup(...)`. This function basically closes the window and refresh the fields in the parent (opener) window. Since I don't have opener set, it returns an error and never closes the iframe. Is there anyway of setting opener on the iframe so that it won't be `null`?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to override the admin view that sends the javascript. These are contained in `django.contrib.admin.options`: the `ModelAdmin.response_add` and `ModelAdmin.response_change` methods. You can simply override these in your model's admin class so that they return the correct fancybox closing code.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thank you very much for replying! However, my main problem now is detailed in this post (i would rather not use iframe if possible): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071338/managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with-after-changed-popup-to